# In Bazaar explorer, want to modify the commit message

Tags: explorer, bazaar

Bazaar explorer i want to modify the commit message after the check-in commit is done.
Is there any Command to modify the commit message done?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the commit message after the commit is done. You can `bzr uncommit` and `bzr commit` with a new message as explained in [Undoing mistakes](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-guide/undoing_mistakes.html#undoing-the-last-commit).